# On mouseout animate line to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now, I've got it to draw a line when you mouseon but I want it so that when you mouseout the line disappears left to right.

https://jsfiddle.net/0ou3o9rn/1/

```
$( "#name" ).mouseover(function() { 

$('.slider').animate({
    width: $('#name').width()
}, 1000);

});
```

Comment: where is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set a `mouseout` handler that animates width to 0:

```
$("#name").mouseover(function () {
    $('.slider').animate({
        width: $('#name').width()
    }, 1000);
}).mouseout(function () {
    $('.slider').animate({
        width: 0
    }, 1000);
});
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ou3o9rn/2/).

But really, if that's *ALL* you want to do, you don't need any JavaScript, just a little CSS:

```css
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    left: 0;
    top:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 0%;
    transition: width 1s;
}
#splash {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
    z-index:999999;
    position:fixed;
}
#name {
    color:#000;
    font-family:'Arial-BoldMT';
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:50px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    display:block;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#name:hover > .slider {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="splash"> <span id="name">random title
    <div class="slider"></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Also as a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ou3o9rn/4/).

The idea here is that you can utilize the `:hover` pseudo-class to modify the style of the child element (the `.slider` class div), and if you set it's `transition` to some value you like (1 second), you get the effect "for free".

Comment: I tried implementing it into the code that I have. https://jsfiddle.net/0ou3o9rn/7/

Answer (score 1):

Hi man try this solution... you won't feel any delays on your animations... or flickering since is CSS animations: https://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/0ou3o9rn/5/

```
<div id="splash"> <span id="name">random title
    <div class="slider out"></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#name").mouseover(function () {
    $('.slider').toggleClass('over');
}).mouseout(function () {
    $('.slider').toggleClass('over');
});
```

CSS

```
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    left: 0;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 0%;
}

#splash {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
    z-index:999999;
    position:fixed;
}
#name {
    color:#000;
    font-family:'Arial-BoldMT';
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:50px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    display:block;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.out{
    -moz-animation: out 0.4s;
    -o-animation: out 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation: out 0.4s;
    animation: out 0.4s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes out {
    from { width:100%;}
    to {width:0}
}

@-moz-keyframes out {
    from { width:100%;}
    to {width:0}
}

@-webkit-keyframes out {
    from { width:100%;}
    to {width:0}
}

.over{
    -moz-animation: over 0.4s;
    -o-animation: over 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation: over 0.4s;
    animation: over 0.4s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes over {
    from { width:0;}
    to {width:100%}
}

@-moz-keyframes over {
    from { width:0;}
    to {width:100%}
}

@-webkit-keyframes over {
    from { width:0;}
    to {width:100%}
}
```

See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/0ou3o9rn/5/

Comment: This other version wouldn't even need javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/0ou3o9rn/6/